# Which is the property of the functions that correspond to this definition/examples?

Tags: functions, associativity

I'm looking for a definition for a particular function(-input) property.
Considering a function $f$ that takes as input a list of elements and produces in output just one element, which is the property that says that the result of $f$ for a given list of elements is EQUAL to the result of the same function $f$ that takes as input a list of elements which are the results of $f$ on subset to the given list?

I provide here some example because I understand the description is quite messy:
Given the list [1,2,3,4,5] the first two examples abide by the property meanwhile the   third does not:

$max([1,2,3,4,5]) = 5 = max([max([1,2]),max([3,4,5])])$ 
$avg([1,2,3,4,5]) = 3 = avg([avg([1,2]),avg([3]),avg([4,5])])$ 
$avg([1,2,3,4,5]) = 3 \neq 2,75 = avg([avg([1,2]),avg([3,4,5])])$

Personally, I think is a sort of functions associativity and I think the second case is just a fortuitous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties like  the one described in the OP  are studied in the context of [aggregation functions](http://books.google.ch/books?id=DbggAwAAQBAJ&hl=it&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (I refer, in particular to pag.32-33 and pag.34 for decomposability). 
As motivating example, I would consider [means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean), [generalized means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean)
and the celebrated [quasi-arithmetic or Kolmogorov-Nagumo means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean).

Comment: Thanks, right what I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcome :) The book is quite nice. It contains many examples coming from applications, like copulae.