# How are functions called which take arbitrary lists of numbers?

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a name for functions like `min`, `max`, `mean`, `sum` which take $n$ numbers and maps them to one number? (In programming, they would probably be called variadic functions... I'm not too sure if this is the right term here)

Comment: I think that there is none; we use $\text{min}$ and $\text{max}$ ambiguously because we can easily recover from the context the number of arguments... (and in any case nothing change in their behaviour).

Comment: If we want to be formal, we have to use *arity*, as in [computability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Role_of_the_projection_functions) where we have *projection functions* $U_i^n$ for every number $n$ of arguments.

Comment: I don't know such a word. But you can define all those you mention recursively as $f(head,tail)$ taking two arguments one element and the rest of the list.

Comment: In addition, we can always reduce them to the "basic" binary case $+(x,y,z)=+(+(x,y),z)$ and $\text {min}(x,y,z)= \text{min}(\text{min}(x,y), z)$

Comment: @user275313 I think that term fits pretty well. Thank you :-) If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it. (And the question should then probably be moved to https://cs.stackexchange.com/ )

Comment: Small note: the comments here about reducing to the binary case/implementing it recursively do not generally apply to these functions: in particular they do not apply to `mean`.

Comment: See @Avitus answer for more about "aggregation functions"
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/923439/720890

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no term I can think of used in mathematics, but in the context of SQL (the standard database query language) the term **aggregating** would be used to describe those functions, precisely for the property you mentioned, i.e. they take a value from multiple rows and return a single value.

By the way, if you check the Wikipedia article on [Relational Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), (which is the mathematical formalism behind SQL), you can [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Aggregation) that 'aggregation' is the term they use, and the functions you mention are four of the five standard functions they mention (you're missing `count`).